# Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.2 md5sum grub files problem

Tags: boot, system-installation, iso, md5sum

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.2 and it hangs on boot with the message "*Gave up waiting for root device on Ubuntu...*".

There are posts about workarounds reintalling grub from a LiveCD|USB session, but none worked form me.

Finally, checking the disc for failures shows 2 files are wrong. I found that md5 sum doesn't match for `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and `/boot/grub/loopback.cfg`. The iso package is correct since md5 sum is the expected.

The expected values for these two files are

```
c915bde902be381c9c268c01fb506e0e
0bf15b6e65732c8efb9793eba1e228b0
```

but I got

```
72289d8c16cac55194e6438103a84c47
46368a1f9f68c3dd76e3f23d3f30a039
```

respectively.

Are these files corrupt from the original iso? Could this be the reason a fresh install doesn't boot? Are the expected md5 values wrong for these files in md5sum.txt file?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.1 and it boots just fine. Surprisingly all md5 sums are mismatched in the iso, except the iso itself, so I don't think that was the problem with 16.04.2.